# AppCompat doesn't work on Xperia Z2

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a question, I've created an application with `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`, but on Xperia Z2 doesn't work. On this phone is only has a ***background color*** and nothing else, but on other phones it's working.

when I use `holo theme,` it is ok, but i use Toolbar and that needs `setSupportActionBar();`

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YU7v2Trd - layout
http://pastebin.com/SGd4wGdQ - activity
http://pastebin.com/Fb58irLe - styles

I rework this application, this is bad code, but i need help with this

Comment: Sorry. It is simple. I have 2 phone (Sony Xperia Z2 and Samsung galaxy S4) and i have application with style (AppCompact), I find bug where on sony xperia Z2 is only activity with background color without any component and on samsung galaxy s4 work all in application. When i use Holo.Light work app so on sony xperia Z2, but i use toolbar and need use appcompact

Comment: I suspect that you have more styles in a values-v## directories. Can you confirm that? Which Android versions run on those devices?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

You should use above codes on your activity.(if you are using AppCompat with NoActionbar)

**Example:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/ampertech_gray">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
<!-- Here is the Toolbar -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnEndTutorial"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEndTutorial"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/jump"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`Actionbar` is Deprecated.Use `AppCompat`.

Example for Toolbar declaration:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call
```

See: http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: I have not problem with toolbar, but Xperia Z2 have problem with AppCompact theme, when i switch theme on Holo, it is OK, but in app i use toolbar and need use AppCompactActivity and this need AppCompact theme

Comment: You should tell us more information **e.x**: a picture of that problem for see if it is a bug or something like that.And i couldn't see any toolbar code on your codes, so, i've added more information about how to using it on your app.Please recheck my answer and if that app.compat doesn't work, let us know.

Comment: My problem is on Xperia Z2, i try comment all code and use only layout with style in layout was only RelativeLayout with GRAY background, style is same like I send. There is result: http://screenshot.cz/R6VQ2/

Comment: Ok.if this is your `Layout`: http://pastebin.com/YU7v2Trd - you didn't add the toolbar.**Please** post your `Styles code` for that `Xperia Z2` with the specified API version (Android version) And of course, if you have new Layouts code, let me know.**You really need to read this:** [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - if you had any question, let us continue this discussion on a chatroom, i'll help you.

Comment: Sony Xperia Z2 - API 21 - 5.0.2
Screenshot - http://screenshot.cz/R6VQ2/
Styles - pastebin.com/Fb58irLe
Layout - http://pastebin.com/YU7v2Trd

Sorry is it my first post.

Comment: So, i told you buddy.you didn't add the toolbar on your `XML`.read my answer and do like i said.you should add that `toolbar xml` code on your **XML** activity.That's because you are using `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` So, it won't show you unless you add that toolbar on your codes.

Comment: I add to xml only toolbar and include to layout, but always no work on Xperia Z2

Comment: What is your IDE? Did you add toolbar declaration on your activity and did you set extends `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Android Studio and yes my activity extends AppCompactActivity. In other activity where is toolbar use is too AppCompatActivity extends

Comment: My answer is correct, but if i'm not wrong, you are using Fragment.check if that toolbar declaration is working on fragment or toolbar is set? By the way, this is an another question and you can read the docs about these things.

Comment: Now i don't understand. I have Activity A (Holo activity - she work) -> ACTIVITY B (I ADD Toolbar (Normal is without toolbar)) -> ACTIVITY C (Is with toolbar)

Comment: Just use `AppCompat` instead of `ActionBarActivity` and after your try with my codes, put the codes here or edit your question if that doesn't work.good day.

Comment: OK. Please look on actual code. I copy your layout to my layout.

http://pastebin.com/5hF10ypf - layout
http://pastebin.com/YAaCNqUR - activity
http://pastebin.com/RSWunGd0 - manifest

thanks you

Comment: Check this out: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14430804/ - Also, if you are using AppCompat, you can use Coordinator Layout with this toolbar too.that `Layout` implementation is not recommended.

Comment: For layout, you can use something like this: http://pastebin.com/xskgS8cx That returns your skills on Android.try to improve it.goodluck!

Comment: This code is not mine. I repair only bugs. I haven't experience with this bug. I try your code and CoordinatorLayout and not change.

Comment: That will work since i've added that toolbar as the toolbar on your activity, check the above links/codes.

Comment: I add your code to app and no change 

http://pastebin.com/wdQkb5A5 - layout
http://pastebin.com/YVcvT3HA - activity

Comment: Try to use: `getSupportActionBar();` in OnCreate method also.

Comment: Try use getSupportActionBar();, but always not work this solution